# error message vulnerability exploitation

Tags: php, html, web, directory, error-messaging

Hi my class has this  thing called a wargame where we have levels and each level has a exploitation due to a cyber security vulnerability  i am stuck on level 4 i know that i am suppose to use the error message cause its giving more information then necessary so we use the information to gain permission to find the password for the next level but i just cant wrap my head around it any advice would be appreciated. The error message is below.

[image]

Comment: You might be having the wrong URL. Check the file location

Comment: Maybe try to access the password file directly ;)

Comment: Your password is in a different level.

Comment: @Rohit.007 how do i check its location?

Comment: @Korri http://ec2-13-58-200-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/passwords/level4password.php'. like this?

Comment: Check your code directory location where you have deployed your code on server.

Comment: @Rohit.007 i am sorry could you please elaborate i dont quite understand because i never deployed a code.